# Spring shell команда с аргументом

Tags: java, spring

Язык: Java, jdk 17
Допустим метод который я реализую простой

```
@ShellMethod
public String hello(String name) 
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Должен вывести имя которое вводим. При вводе имени например `hello Jack` все нормально работает. Но если попробовать с фамилией, например, `Hello Jack Jarkov` выведет только `Hello Jack`.
Подскажите почему? И как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать вместо одного имени несколько имён, используя `vararg` синтаксис:

```java
@ShellMethod
public String hello(String ... names) 
{
    return "Hello " + String.join(" ", names);
}
```

Comment: Всё равно выводит только первое слово